# Using nodejs/electron and calling python scripts, how can I create a python object and call different methods from it along the execution?

Tags: python, node.js, function, child-process

I am running an app using nodejs/electron and python.
I have 4 files: index.html, index.js, index.py and USER.py

In the index.html I have two buttons and a text input for specify an id of a user called 'idUser'.

In the index.js I have:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn, py = spawn('python', ['index.py']),dataString = '';

    py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
        dataString += data.toString();
        console.log(dataString);
    });  

    py.stdout.on('end', function(){
       console.log('answer=',dataString);
    });

    py.stdin.end();
```

In the index.py I have:

```
from USER import *
user=USER('user1','34')
```

And finally, in the USER.py I have:

```
class USER:
   id=''
   name=''
   age=''
   def __init__(self,name,age):
        ....blah blah blah...

   def getName(self,id):
        ....blah blah blah....

   def getAge(self,id):
        ....blah blah blah....
```

At the beginning of the execution using javascript (child_process) I create a python object called 'user' executing the javascript file, works perfecty. Now, here is the question:

I want to call `user.getName(idUser)` or `user.getAge(idUser)` with the buttons in the HTML whenever I want while I use the application.

Sincerelly I cannot figure out how to use the same object from different javascript files in order to use the information along the app.

Comment: Looks like you want use DJango ?

Comment: maybe, I will learn it just in case, but I really want to use nodejs. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: https://medium.com/@HolmesLaurence/integrating-node-and-python-6b8454bfc272